# Merging and appending tables to create a master table of multiple tables

Tags: awk, merge, gawk, table

How to we can merge and append the multiple tables in the same format having same as well as different data point and merge all of the together by inputting zero to the null data points. Desired input files are

File1

```
17      64298926        0.000599042
17      64298927        0.000399361
17      64298992        0.000199681
17      64299103        0.000399361
17      64299131        0.000199681
```

File2

```
17      64298959        0.76087
17      64299360        0.75
17      64299462        1
17      64299584        0.5
```

File3

```
17      64298930        0.0016835
17      64298939        0.00117647
17      64298959        0.0888383
17      64298980        0.00111359
17      64299003        0.0011236
17      64299014        0.00239234
17      64299026        0.00132626
17      64299030        0.00125628
17      64299039        0.00112867
17      64299041        0.00112108
17      64299058        0.00110619
17      64299101        0.00114155
17      64299123        0.00114943
17      64299152        0.00115741
```

.
.
.
.
.
till
FileN

And the desired output should be some thing like this

```
17  64298926    0.000599042 0   0
17  64298927    0.000399361 0   0
17  64298992    0.000199681 0   0
17  64299103    0.000399361 0   0
17  64299131    0.000199681 0   0
17  64298959    0   0.76087 0.0888383
17  64299360    0   0.75    0
17  64299462    0   1   0
17  64299584    0   0.5 0
17  64298930    0   0   0.0016835
17  64298939    0   0   0.00117647
17  64298980    0   0   0.00111359
17  64299003    0   0   0.0011236
17  64299014    0   0   0.00239234
17  64299026    0   0   0.00132626
17  64299030    0   0   0.00125628
17  64299039    0   0   0.00112867
17  64299041    0   0   0.00112108
17  64299058    0   0   0.00110619
17  64299101    0   0   0.00114155
17  64299123    0   0   0.00114943
17  64299152    0   0   0.00115741
```

The no of column extra adding should be n-1 to the no of files

Is there any shortcut (single liners ) to do so ??

Answer (score 2):

A long `awk` oneliner:

```
awk '{keys[$2]=$1; filenames[FILENAME]++; values[FILENAME,$2]=$3}END{for (k in keys){printf("%s %s ", keys[k], k); for (f in filenames){printf("%s ", values[f,k]?values[f,k]:0)} printf("\n");}} ' File? | sort
```

Here's the output, given your above files:

```
17 64298926 0.000599042 0 0 
17 64298927 0.000399361 0 0 
17 64298930 0 0 0.0016835 
17 64298939 0 0 0.00117647 
17 64298959 0 0.76087 0.0888383 
17 64298980 0 0 0.00111359 
17 64298992 0.000199681 0 0 
17 64299003 0 0 0.0011236 
17 64299014 0 0 0.00239234 
17 64299026 0 0 0.00132626 
17 64299030 0 0 0.00125628 
17 64299039 0 0 0.00112867 
17 64299041 0 0 0.00112108 
17 64299058 0 0 0.00110619 
17 64299101 0 0 0.00114155 
17 64299103 0.000399361 0 0 
17 64299123 0 0 0.00114943 
17 64299131 0.000199681 0 0 
17 64299152 0 0 0.00115741 
17 64299360 0 0.75 0 
17 64299462 0 1 0 
17 64299584 0 0.5 0
```

I arbitrarily used a space as the output separator.

And here's the unrolled script:

```
{
    keys[$2]=$1; 
    filenames[FILENAME]++; 
    values[FILENAME,$2]=$3
}
END {
    for (k in keys) {
        printf("%s %s ", keys[k], k); 
        for (f in filenames) { 
            printf("%s ", values[f,k]?values[f,k]:0)
        } 
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```